# Write a program to return the length of the longest word from a string whose length is even?

Tags: java, string, count, max

```
Optional<Integer> opInt = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s")).stream()
  .map(l -> l.length())
  .filter(l -> l % 2 == 0)
  .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
  .findFirst();
System.out.println(opInt.get());
```

Have written code above for that. Can we write concise code for it.

Comment: Is code-golf back?

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(…).stream()`, use `Arrays.stream(…)` to create a `Stream` in the first place, without a `List` detour. Replace `map` with `mapToInt`, to get to an `IntStream` because then you can change `.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).findFirst()` to `max().orElse(0)` (use `.orElse(0)` to get an `int` rather than optional int)

Comment: `.map(String::length)` instead of `.map(l -> l.length())`? Is that even "more concise"? And why?

Comment: `OptionalInt longest = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s")).stream().mapToInt(String::length).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).max();` maybe

Comment: Understood.  Code be written as below. Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s")).stream().mapToInt(String::length).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).max().orElse(0);

Comment: Or, combining it with the print statement if that’s the only operation: `Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")) .mapToInt(String::length) .filter(l -> l % 2 == 0) .max() .ifPresent(System.out::println);` Note that `"\s"` is the same as `" "` (a single space). To match arbitrary space characters, you have to quote the backslash with another backslash and usually, you want to treat multiple space characters as a single separator, hence `"\\s+"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of using `Arrays.asList().stream()`, use `Arrays.stream(…)`.
2. You can use method reference instead of using the lambda. `l -> l.length()`.
3. You can replace `.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())` with a
   `.max()`
4. Refactored Code:

```java
  final OptionalInt max = Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
      .mapToInt(String::length)
      .filter(l -> l % 2 == 0)
      .max();

  System.out.println(max.orElse(0));
```